# Distinct over several field but show all field SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have a query with a result like this

```
No    date           No.PO     product    type       div         price
1.      01-10-2012   |    AAA1  |     X1   |    1   |     SBS   |      100
2.      09-10-2012   |    ABA1  |     X1   |    2   |     SBS   |      150
3.      11-10-2012   |    ACC1  |     X1   |    1   |     SBS   |      110
4.      15-10-2012   |    ACD1  |     X1   |    1   |     DBS   |      115
5.      20-10-2012   |    ADA1  |     X1   |    1   |     SBS   |      112
6.      23-10-2012   |    AFA1  |     X1   |    2   |     SBS   |      160
7.      27-10-2012   |    AHA1  |     X1   |    1   |     SBS   |      120
```

and a few thousand record . . .

and the result should be show like this

```
No        date           No.PO     product    type        div         price
1.      27-10-2012   |    AHA1  |     X1   |    1   |     SBS   |       120
2.      23-10-2012   |    AFA1  |     X1   |    2   |     SBS   |       160
3.      15-10-2012   |    ACD1  |     X1   |    1   |     DBS   |       115
```

Here is the rules

1. Distinct on product type and div
2. Only the last transaction that i wanna show (it means the biggest date among the duplicate  product, type and div data)
3. All of the field (date, No.PO, product, type, div and price) must be showed

Hopefully my description is clear now . .

Anyone can help me with the right query?

Comment: i've tried using using lag(actually emulate lag because i use SQL Server 2008) to compare of product, type, div of the previous value but the query is too slow

Comment: @Javaboy - Please explain your expected result. Why the date `27-10-2012` came in result and `01-10-2012` did not come.

Comment: sorry if my description is not clear enough  . .
i only want the last transaction with distict of product type and div that show on my query

Comment: Can you post your query here?

Comment: can't post my own question because i'm a newbie here i'll post here then sorry if this is not readable --->

with q1 as(
    SELECT
    row_number() over(order by product, date desc) As row,
    date, noPO, product, type, div, price
    from table
    )
    select q1.*
    from q1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN q1 AS qLg ON q1.row = qLg.row + 1
    where (q1.product<>isnull(qLg.product,'-') 
    or q1.type<>isnull(qLg.type,'-') 
    or q1.div<>isnull(qLg.div,'-') 
    order by product, date desc

Comment: Whenever you say "I want these columns to be distinct, but I want to include more columns", you're describing a `GROUP BY` or `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` operation. But, in order for us to be able to formulate it (or for SQL Server to make sense of it), we need *you* to formulate the **rules** for how we select values for those other columns - because we're effectively reducing multiple rows down into a single row, there are multiple values to select for each column. Please try to clearly formulate what rule(s) you want to use ("Random" or "arbitrary" is not a rule)

Comment: i've edit my rules now . . hopefully it is clear now . . sorry to make everyone gueesing my rules . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the query and check the result, mere guess.

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by [Type], [Div] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) RowNum,
        [Date], 
        [No.PO], 
        [Product], 
        [Type], 
        [Div], 
        [Price] 
    FROM TABLE_Name
)x WHERE RowNum=1 
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Comment: I'll try with this method . .

Comment: this method works but instead using DENSE_RANK i use ROW_NUMBER . . but still tour anwer inspiring me . . thanks techdo
if my query above took about 20 minutes with this method it tooks around 1 minute . . Still too long . .